# JHipster: How turn prompt optional in my blueprint when executing the "jdl" command

Tags: jhipster, prompt, blueprint

I've observed the following behavior when I generate a new application using JHipster:

1. When I just call `jhipster`, it shows a set of prompts to make my choices.
2. When I call `jhipster jdl <myjslfile.jdl>`:
   2.1. If the JDL has just entities, not declaring a config application section, I've got an  error: `Database type is required to validate entities`.
   2.2. If the JDL has the minimum config application like the following, it assumes some defaults and does not show any prompt.

I'm trying to write my own blueprint and I'd like to know how could I tell to Jhipster some default values should be considered when loading a JDL.

I thought that if I just set the prompt attribute `default` would be the solution, but I did this and have no effect, the prompts are always shown. When there are more than one application declared in the JDL file it's worst because it's not possible to distinguish what is being answered to each application since this processes happen in parallel.

Regards,

```
application {
  config {
    baseName microserviceExample,
    applicationType microservice,
    prodDatabaseType postgresql
  }
  entities X
}

entity X {
  name String required minlength(3)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I don't like depending on default values that could be changed by a new major version (e.g. default for service registry will change in JHipster 8 from Eureka to Consul).

Why is this a problem to explicit these values in your JDL? For me the JDL should be self contained as much as possible.

Alternatively, you could define a  `.yo-rc.json` file in your project directory or in its parent directory if you want to apply to several apps below.

And finally, you could open a feature request on github for the dev team to comment.

Comment: I don't want specify a default value to an existing config, I'm creating a new blueprint and created a new config option that makes sense just to my own blueprint. My intention is that the behavior be the same as original Jhipster blueprint: if it's running from a JDL file. However, I've noticed that this default values are set inside the jdl-importer and it seems to be fixed, it just set defaults based on the applicationType, not the generator/blueprint. 
I'd like to know how people do in this case, do they always prompt? What happen when many applications are generated in parallel? Thanks!